# How do I remove space in between list characters when I print?

Tags: python

Ive tried making a small password generator and want to eventually send the output to a txt file, however when I print my list there are spaces in between each character and I cant find a solution to remove it.

Here is my code:

```
import string
import random

pwdlen = 0
holder = 0
mainlist = []

print('Enter Number of Characters Wanted:')
pwdlen = int(input())
print('Your', pwdlen, 'Character Password is:')

while holder != pwdlen:
    dec = (random.randrange(1, 5))
    holder += 1
    if dec == 1:
        mainlist.append(random.choice(string.digits))
    elif dec == 2:
        mainlist.append(random.choice(string.punctuation))
    elif dec == 3:
        mainlist.append(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))
    else:
        mainlist.append(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase))
else:
    print(*mainlist)
```

here is an example of the output I get.

```
D ~ 8 { > 5 x 0 H B 6 * ' 0 \ h 2 9 ~ { 1 p
```

But Id like to space removed like so.

```
D~8{>5x0HB6*'0\h29~{1p
```

Thanks for the help. Im using pychrarm and python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `sep` (separator) argument and set it to the empty string.

```
print(*mainlist, sep='')
```

`print()`'s optional arguments are explained in its doc:

```
>>> help(print)
Help on built-in function print in module builtins:

print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
    flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Crazy that is was this simple I spent hours trying to fix it.